# How to view the confirmation email sent from Firebase auth emulator (web) on localhost?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm running a Next.js app on localhost port 3000. With Firebase email/password signup, I use `auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();` to send an email with the Firebase auth emulator running. During development on localhost I'd like to be able to intercept, view the email and click the redirect link.

I've been using MailDev with Nodemailer on the nodejs backend to intercept emails sent from the backend, but I've been unable to find how to do something similar with these Firebase emails, such as send them to MailDev, which is receiving email on localhost:1025

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The emulators don't actually send an email for the verification, but instead print a URL on the console that you can open to verify the email. See the documentation on [Emulated email, email link and anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#emulated_email_email_link_and_anonymous_authentication).

The only way to get the verification emails is to test against the actual project, and not in the emulator suite.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way, more automated:

Here is the auth log output for a new user within the Emulator:
[image: Emulator Auth Log]

Then base on [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-auth-emulator-oob) you can fetch the oobCodes (out of band
codes) with restAPI:

[image]

Also documentation described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#emulated_email_email_link_and_anonymous_authentication)