Firebase Authentication sendEmailVerification Not Sending Email
I'm currently working on an app to uses Firebase's Authentication service.
I implemented email verification using Firebase's sendEmailVerification after users have done createUserWithEmailAndPassword, and am testing it with the Firebase Emulator Suite.
I receive no error on the app when running this, but I don't receive any verification emails in my inbox or spam.
Are there any configurations I need to do on the Firebase console?
Below is how I am invoking the sendEmailVerification call.
// Submit form
try {
  switch (formType) {
    case "signIn":
      let signInResult = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      )
      userObject = signInResult.user
      toaster.create({
        title: "Signed in successfully.",
        type: "success",
        duration: 3500
      })
      break
    case "signUp":
      // Sign up user
      let signUpResult = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      )
      userObject = signUpResult.user
      // Update user profile with a random username

      console.log(
        "Attempting to send email verification",
        userObject,
        actionCodeSettings
      )
      await sendEmailVerification(userObject)
      toaster.create({
        title: "Email verification sent to your inbox.",
        type: "success",
        duration: 3500
      })

      await updateProfile(signUpResult.user, {
        displayName: generateUsername()
      })
      console.log("SUCCESSFULLY SIGNED UP")
      setSignedUp(true)
      toaster.create({
        title: "Signed up successfully.",
        type: "success",
        duration: 3500
      })
      break
    case "forgetPassword":
      await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
      toaster.create({
        title: "Password reset email sent.",
        type: "success",
        duration: 3500
      })
      break
    default:
      break
  }

  // If user is signing in or signing up, submit journal entries
  if (["signIn", "signUp"].includes(formType)) {
    await handleJournalSubmission(userObject, "qotd")
    await handleJournalSubmission(userObject, "thought")
  }
} catch (error) {
  const firebaseError = error as AuthError
  toaster.create({
    title: "An error has occurred.",
    description: firebaseError.code,
    type: "error",
    duration: 3500
  })
} finally {
  // resetForm()
  // isOpen.update(false)
}

Update: The email is sent only on the deployed hosted domain, not in localhost development. Is there something specific I have to configure in the Firebase console? I checked the Authorized Domains and localhost is included. Not sure what else is causing the email not to be sent in development.

If the sendEmailVerification call returns without an error, the email has very likely been sent (as otherwise you'd get an error). If you don't see the email in your inbox, check your spam folder and any spam filters en route between Google's servers and your mail server.

Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen for your comment. I have double-checked all my emails in my mailbox and cannot find anything related to Firebase in spam, inbox, or other places to which the email could be sent. Is there any other way to check that an email was sent? Perhaps in the Firebase console that you of?

Update: The email sends fine once I've deployed the app and tried it on the deployed hosted domain. Is there anything I have to configure in Firebase console to do localhost testing?

I'm not sure I follow: what do you mean with "localhost testing"? Are you running the Firebase emulator suite? That indeed does not send an email, but rather prints some information on the console: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66628765/209103

Yes, I am running the Firebase emulator suite in development, but it does not send an email. How can I test the full authentication flow with email verification in development if the Firebase emulator doesn't send the email?

The emulator suite indeed will not send email verifications. From the link: The only way to get the verification emails is to test against [an] actual project, and not in the emulator suite."
